# "double" does not contain a definition and no extension method could be found?

Tags: c#, .net

'double' does not contain a definition for 'getMaxTemp' and no extension method 'getMaxTemp' accepting a first argument of type 'double' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is used in the context of

```
Console.WriteLine("\nLake Nepessing temperatures");
        Console.WriteLine(" Min temperature: " + Lake.getMinTemp(Nepessing));
        Console.WriteLine(" Max temperature: " + Lake.getMaxTemp(Nepessing));
```

What exactly am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, where is getMaxTemp etc defined?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `Lake` is a variable which you have declared of type [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) so you cannot call `getMinTemp` method on it unless it is a custom [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) in which case make sure that you have included the proper namespace in which this extension method was declared.

So there are three possibilities to make this work:

1. `getMinTemp` is a static method on the `Lake` class.
2. `getMinTemp` is an instance method on some class and `Lake` is an instance of this class
3. `getMinTemp` is an extension method on whatever the type of the `Lake` variable is.